# Using scalar functions with Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, user-defined-functions

I have this problem. I have a scalar SQL Server function:

```
USE [app_sys]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[decrypt]
    (@password nvarchar(30))
RETURNS nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @salasana nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @decrypted nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @T int, @TT int, @x1 int, @sana int, @g int, @m int, @v int, @pomosna int

    SET @decrypted = ''
    SET @salasana = ''
    SET @X1 = 0
    SET @v = LEN(@salasana) - 1
    SET @T = 0
    SET @TT = 0

    WHILE @T <= @v 
    BEGIN
        SET @sana = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@salasana, @T, 1))
        SET @X1 = @X1 + @sana 
        SET @T = @T + 1 
    END

    SET @X1 = CAST((@X1 * 0.1) / 6 AS integer) 
    SET @salasana = Char(@X1) 
    SET @G = 0 
    SET @m = LEN(@password) - 1
        
    WHILE @TT <= @m 
    BEGIN
        SET @sana = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@password, @TT + 1, 1)) 
        SET @G = @G + 1 

        IF @G = 6 
           SET @G = 0 

        SET @X1 = 0 
        SET @pomosna = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@salasana, 1, 1))

        IF @G = 0 
           SET @X1 = @sana + (@pomosna - 2)

        IF @G = 1 
           SET @X1 = @sana - (@pomosna - 5)

        IF @G = 2 
           SET @X1 = @sana + (@pomosna - 4)

        IF @G = 3 
           SET @X1 = @sana - (@pomosna - 2)

        IF @G = 4 
           SET @X1 = @sana + (@pomosna - 3)

        IF @G = 5 
           SET @X1 = @sana - (@pomosna - 5)

        SET @X1 = @X1 - @G 
        SET @decrypted = @decrypted + Char(@X1)
        SET @TT = @TT + 1
    END
 
    RETURN @decrypted
END
```

I need to use this function in an ASP.NET MVC project. I made a connection to database with Entity Framework 6, but the problem is that this is a scalar function so I suppose I need to add a a custom method in my context class so I can access this method with a object of the context class.

My question is according to this function that takes one parameter how should the method in my context class look like. If this was a table function this method would be generated by EF, but I need help since its scalar function

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I use Microsoft Server SQL .

Comment: I wouldn't touch this code with a bargepole, it has so many issues. Firstly the whole concept of reversible encryption for a password is wrong, it should be hashed. And this isn't encryption so much as obfuscation, because there is no encryption key. You are passing in `nvarchar` but using `ASCII()` and `CHAR()` instead of `UNICODE()` and `NCHAR()`.  And this type of thing should probably be done in SQLCLR instead of T-SQL if you *really* had to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute scalar function from EF directly, but you can write something like this:

```
internal static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static T SqlScalarResult<T>(DbContext db, string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters, string schema = "dbo")
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("function");
        }

        if (parameters == null || parameters.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("parameters");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("schema");
        }

        string cmdText = $@"SELECT {schema}.{sql}({string.Join(",", parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.ParameterName).ToList())});";

        return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(cmdText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    public string GetDecryptedPassword(string encryptedPassword)
    {
        using (_context = new YourDBContext())
        {
            var p1 = new SqlParameter("password", encryptedPassword);
            SqlParameter[] parameters = { p1 };

            return DatabaseExtensions.SqlScalarResult<string>(_context, "decrypt", parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "You can't execute scalar function from EF" can you not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Comment: Means you cannot import it like stored procedures.